# AG-Grid export Excel in RTL mode

Tags: excel, export, ag-grid

Does ag-grid `exportDataAsExcel` function support RTL? For example when my grid locale is Arabic (`enableRtl=true`) I want to export to Excel columns in RTL order, but it appears in LTR mode like in English locale.

`prependContent` is possible solution, but it looks ugly, I hope grid provide something for it.

Comment: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/excel-export-api/#excelalignment `readingOrder`

Comment: As I understand it reverse words, but not columns :(

Comment: I see. Best I can quickly see is to set [`columnKeys`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/excel-export-api/#reference-ExcelExportParams-columnKeys). Use something like `columnApi.getAllColumns()` to get a list of columns, then reverse the array.